# Can't get to localhost:3000 and welcome to express

Tags: node.js, installation

I have just started learning node.js and I have been following [this](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/) tutorial.
I did all the things mentioned there but when I write `npm start` on the cmd I couldn't go to the "welcome to express" page. I have attached the screenshot with the errors I am getting.

I googled a lot of things but couldn't find an answer.

here are the screenshots:
[image: screenshots]

P.s. ->(If this is worth mentioning) I also executed `npm install mysql` (from some other tutorial since I wanted to use mysql) instead of mongodb written in the linked tutorial.

Comment: `npm install` in the root of your application? You're clearly missing some module(s).

Comment: which one? and how can I fix it?

Comment: screen #3 says you're missing `promise` module.

Comment: so how do i install it?? npm install promise?

Comment: according to the tutorial `npm install` would install all the dependencies. I alreadywrote that command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try that :

1. Delete the whole node_modules directory
2. Launch "npm install" to reinstall all node_modules
3. Try again

If you still have a problem, share your package.json file.

Comment: I created a new project and wrote npm-install. It's working fine now. Thanks